# Getting proper interline spacing in a node in a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have text in two nodes typeset on more than one line. The interline spacing on the node containing "future vertex" is unappealing. I had to include the `\\{}` to put more space between two of the lines. Without it, the interline spacing gives the text in the node a cramped appearance.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize}, shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-n.
\draw (-4,-9) -- (-2,-9) -- (0,-9) (2,-9) -- (5,-9);
\draw[fill] (-4,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\node at (1,-9){$\ldots$};
\draw[fill] (2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,-9) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of last two vertices and the label of the mediants of these vertices.
\draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$) -- (3.5,-9);
\path node[anchor=south, align=center] at ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$){future vertex\\of\\{}\\$\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Edge) at ($(3.5,-9.5) +(0,-0.75)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3.5,-9) -- (label_for_Edge);
\node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at (label_for_Edge)
{Present edge label of\\$2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr]$\\$=2^{2}b-(2n+1)2$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(La)TeX is so attractive because it has means to provide you with proper spacing. Many of the equation type environments however only work if they "know" the text width, i.e. you need to put them in minipage-like structures. You can get these structures in nodes by adding the `text width` key. This allows you to use `\[...\]` as in

```
\path node[anchor=south, align=center,text width={width("future vertex")}] 
    at ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$){future vertex\\of\[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\]};
```

which then uses the LaTeX spacing for equations. Of course, you are not limited to `\[...\]`, this is just an example. For the second equation I use `multline` but what is best depends on your own preferences. You can further adjust the spaces by redefining `\belowdisplayskip`, e.g.  `\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.75ex}`. I do that locally in the nodes for now, but you can do that inside the `tikzpicture` environment, too`

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.75ex}}}, 
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-n.
\draw (-4,-9) -- (-2,-9) -- (0,-9) (2,-9) -- (5,-9);
\draw[fill] (-4,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\node at (1,-9){$\ldots$};
\draw[fill] (2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,-9) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of last two vertices and the label of the mediants of these vertices.
\draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$) -- (3.5,-9);
\path node[anchor=south, align=center,text width={width("future vertex")}] 
at ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$){future vertex\\of\[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\]};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Edge) at ($(3.5,-9.5) +(0,-0.75)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3.5,-9) -- (label_for_Edge);
\node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
,text width={width("Present edge label of")}] at (label_for_Edge)
{Present edge label of
\begin{multline*}2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr]\\=2^{2}b-(2n+1)2
\end{multline*}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With use of the `multipart` node shape and some effort to make your code shorter:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,           % new
                positioning,      % new
                shapes.multipart} % new

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 7mm and 21mm,  % new
  start chain = going right,   % new
dot/.style args = {#1/#2}{circle, draw, fill, minimum size=3pt, inner sep=0pt,
                          label=$#1$,
                          label=below:$#2$,
                          node contents={},
                          on chain}, % new
lbl/.style args = {#1/#2}{rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                          font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt,   
                          node contents={#1\nodepart{two}#2},
                          }, % new
                    ]
\node (n1) [dot=\frac{0}{1}/b];
\node (n2) [dot=\frac{1}{1}/b-1];
\node (n3) [dot=\frac{2}{1}/b-2];
\node (n4) [dot=\frac{n}{1}/b-n];
\node (n5) [dot=\frac{n+1}{1}/b-(n+1)];
%
\draw[thick]    (n1) -- (n3)   (n4) -- node (aux) {} (n5);
\path           (n3) -- node {$\dotsm$} (n4);
% "pin" above
\draw[latex- , dashed, semithick]
        (aux) -- ++ (6mm,9mm) node[above, lbl=Future vertex of/
                                              $\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$];
% "pin" below
\draw[semithick]
        (aux) -- ++ (0,-9mm) node[below, lbl=Present edge label of/
                                             {$\begin{gathered}
                                                  2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr]\\
                                                   = 2^{2}b-(2n+1)2 
                                               \end{gathered}$}];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]