# Consistency in drawing `(Point A) to[bend right=30] (Point B)` in a `TikZ` diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the following `TikZ` diagram, I have depicted an expanding graph - a sequence of simple graphs. The commands resembling

```
\draw[-latex] (Point A) to[bend right=30] (Point B)
```

indicate the expansion at a certain step. This looks nice when `(Point A)` is directly above `(Point B)` - the arrowhead is going into the northwest corner of a node containing a fraction. The third - and last - one of these arrows ends at a `(Point B)` that is southeast of a `(Point A)`. (The `(Point B)` in this case contains the fraction `1/1` typeset in green. It is a temporary node that is typeset to illustrate my concern.) In this case, the arrowhead looks like it is going into the western edge of the node. How can this last arrow be modified to that the arrowhead is going into the northeast corner of the node?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1}]

%A sequence of graphs is drawn, starting with the vertex with the b-label b.


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b.
\draw[fill] (-4,0) circle (1.5pt);
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,0) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,0) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
%
\draw (-4,-3) -- (-2,-3);
\draw[fill] (-4,-3) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-3) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b) at ($(-4,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,-3) +(0,-0.25)$){$b - 1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-3) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
%
%An arrow is drawn to the next diagram.
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex \textit{b}} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b);


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-1.
\draw (-4,-6) -- (-2,-6) -- (0,-6);
\draw[fill] (-4,-6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-6) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-6) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-6) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-6) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-6) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1) at ($(-2,-6) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,-6) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-6) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);


%Here is the blow-up of the vertex labeled b-n.
\draw (-4,-9) -- (-2,-9) -- (0,-9) (2,-9) -- (5,-9);
\draw[fill] (-4,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\node at (1,-9){$\ldots$};
\draw[fill] (2,-9) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,-9) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=south, green] (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses) at ($(1,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,-9) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,-9) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%
%
%
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\more vertices} (label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses);
%
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of last two vertices and the label of the mediants of these vertices.
\draw[-latex, dashed, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=3mm, shorten >=1mm] ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$) -- (3.5,-9);
\path node[anchor=south, align=center, text width={width("future vertex")}]
at ($(3.5,-9) +(60:2)$){future mediant\\for vertex\[\dfrac{2n+1}{2}\]};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
\coordinate (label_for_Edge) at ($(3.5,-9.5) +(0,-0.75)$);
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (3.5,-9) -- (label_for_Edge);
\node[anchor=north, align=center, inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize] at (label_for_Edge)
{$\begin{aligned} &\text{Present edge label of} \\[-1.5ex]
&\quad 2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr] \\[-1.5ex]
&\qquad=2^{2}b-(2n+1)2
\end{aligned}$};



\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-1) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\vertex $b - 1$} (label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b-1);


\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=30pt, shorten >=7.5pt] (label_for_Edge.south) -- ($(label_for_Edge.south) +(0,-4)$);

%Here is the vertex placed at the broken edge.
\draw (-4,-15) -- (-2,-15) -- (0,-15) (2,-15) -- (5,-15);
\draw[fill] (-4,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (-2,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (0,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\node at (1,-15){$\ldots$};
\draw[fill] (2,-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] ({(2+5)/2},-15) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (5,-15) circle (1.5pt);
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-4,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-4,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{0}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(-2,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-1$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(-2,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{1}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(0,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(0,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(2,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){\textit{b-n}};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(2,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n}{1}$};
%
\node[anchor=north] at ($(5,-15) +(0,-0.25)$){$b-(n+1)$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($(5,-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{n+1}{1}$};
%
%A "pin" is drawn between the midpoint of the edge between the last two vertices and its label.
\draw[draw=gray, line width=0.8pt, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] ({(2+5)/2},-15) -- ({(2+5)/2},-16);
\node[anchor=north] at ({(2+5)/2},-16){$2^{2}b-(n+1)2$};
\node[anchor=south] at ($({(2+5)/2},-15) +(0,0.25)$){$\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Load `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}` and use `\draw[-{Latex[bend]}, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] ...` instead.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat  I decided to have the arrowhead end at a point `1mm` above the node containing the fraction `1/1` typeset in green. Since the fraction is not going to be typeset, I think this is appropriate.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat  I would encode `$\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{1}}$` to give the node the right height.

Comment: So, I encoded ...

Comment: ... `\coordinate (point_just_above_node_containing_phantom_Farey_Fraction) at ($(label_for_phantom_Farey_Fraction_at_ellipses.north) +(0,0.1)$);`

Comment: ... `\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt, shorten=7.5pt] (label_for_Vertex_b-2) to[bend right=30] node[midway, left=1.5mm, align=center]
{Blow-up of\\more vertices} (point_just_above_node_containing_phantom_Farey_Fraction);`

Comment: ... and it looks just fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

**Edit:**
MWE below is based on my  [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517981/getting-proper-interline-spacing-in-a-node-in-a-tikz-diagram/518833#518833) on your previous question. It is organized in five rows, which  are consist of building blocks (BBB) -- nodes `dot` -- with the following structure: black filled circle, label with name above it (where are fractions 0/1, 1/1, 2/1, etc)  and label with name below it (where are indices `b`, `b-1`, etc). Labels' names enable drawing arrow between BBBs in neighborhood rows:

```
 dot/.style args = {#1/#2/#3/#4}{circle, draw, fill, minimum size=3pt,
                    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                    label={[name=#1]$#2$},
                    label={[name=#3]below:$#4$},
                    node contents={},
                    on chain},
```

Defined BBB are connected in chains in each image row by use of `chains` library. Distance between them are determined by `node distance=<vertical> and <horizontal>`.

Beside BBB are defined auxiliary element as `lbl` for pin nodes, style of labels, edge quotes and node distance. With the last are defined distances between BBB. With this is simple to change distances between BBB on the consistent way.

Described structure proposed solution enable (of course to my opinion) a consistent, concise and short code for your image, which can be simply extend with new images' elements if necessary.

Complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,           % new
                positioning,      % new
                shapes.multipart, % new
                quotes}           % new  
\makeatletter
\tikzset{% for discontinuing of chain
  off chain/.code={\def\tikz@lib@on@chain{}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
           node distance = 22mm and 21mm,    % new
             start chain = going right,     % new
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right, font=\footnotesize,
                            align=center},  % new
every edge/.append style = {-latex, line width=0.8pt},
      every label/.style = {inner sep= 2pt,font=\footnotesize},
         dot/.style args = {#1/#2/#3/#4}{circle, draw, fill, minimum size=3pt,
                            inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center,
                            label={[name=#1]$#2$},
                            label={[name=#3]below:$#4$},
                            node contents={},
                            on chain}, % 
         lbl/.style args = {#1/#2}{rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
                            font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt,
                            node contents={#1\nodepart{two}#2},
                            }, % new
                    ]
%%%% 1. row (is on the top of image), node name is n11
\node (n11) [dot=n11a/\frac{0}{1}/n11b/b];
%%%% 2. row, nodes names are n21, n22
\node (n21) [dot=n21a/\frac{0}{1}/n21b/b,
            below=of n11];
\node (n22) [dot=n22a/\frac{1}{1}/n22b/b-];
\draw[-latex, line width=0.8pt]
        (n11b) edge["blow up\\ of vertex $b$", bend left] (n21a);
\draw   (n21) -- (n22);
%%%% 3. row, nodes names are n31, n32, ...
\node (n31) [dot=n31a/\frac{0}{1}/n31b/b,
            below=of n21];
\node (n32) [dot=n32a/\frac{1}{1}/n32b/b-1];
\node (n33) [dot=n33a/\frac{2}{1}/n33b/b-2];
\draw   (n22b) edge["blow up\\  of vertex $b$", bend left] (n32a);
\draw   (n31) -- (n33);
%%%% 4. row, nodes names are n41, n42, ...
\node (n41) [dot=n41a/\frac{0}{1}/n41b/b,
            below=of n31];
\node (n42) [dot=n42a/\frac{1}{1}/n42b/b-1];
\node (n43) [dot=n43a/\frac{2}{1}/n43b/b-2];
\node (n44) [dot=n45a/\frac{n}{1}/n45b/b-n];
\node (n45) [dot=n46a/\frac{n+1}{1}/n46b/b-(n+1)];
\path   (n43) -- node[inner sep=0pt,
                      label={[name=n46,text=green!40!black]$\frac{3}{1}$}] {$\dots$} (n44);
\draw   (n33b) edge["blow up\\  of vertex $b$",
                    bend left] (n43a);
\draw   (n33b) edge[bend left] (n46.north);
\draw[thick]    (n41) -- (n43)   (n44) -- node (aux) {} (n45);
% "pin" above
\draw[<-, semithick, dashed]   (aux) -- ++ (6mm,9mm) 
        node[above, lbl=Future vertex of/
                        $\dfrac{2n+1}{2}$];
% "pin" below
\draw[semithick]    (aux) -- ++ (0,-9mm) 
        node (aux2) [below, lbl=Present edge label of/
                                {$\begin{gathered}
                                2\bigl[(b-n)+(b-(n+1))\bigr]\\
                                = 2^{2}b-(2n+1)2
                                \end{gathered}$}];
%%%% 5. row, nodes names are n51, n52, ...
\node (n51) [dot=n51a/\frac{0}{1}/n41b/b,
            below=of n41 |- aux2];
\node (n52) [dot=n52a/\frac{1}{1}/n52b/b-1];
\node (n53) [dot=n53a/\frac{2}{1}/n53b/b-2];
\node (n54) [dot=n54a/\frac{n}{1}/n54b/b-n];
\node (n55) [dot=n55a/\frac{n+1}{1}/n55b/b-(n+1)];
%
\path   (n53) -- node [anchor=center] {$\dots$} (n54);
\draw[thick]    (n51) --  (n53) 
                (n54) --  (n55) node (n56) [pos=0.5, off chain, 
                                      dot=n56a/\frac{2n+1}{2}/n56b/ ];
\draw[semithick]
        (aux2) -- (n56a) (n56) -- ++ (0,-9mm) node[below, lbl={$2^{2}b-(2n+1)2$/ }];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note, I'm aware that my proposed solution is quite different from yours, which you use so far. Anyway, it is worth (according to my opinion) to test it and see alternative solution, which may offer more easy way to manage it, simpler change or maintain consistency.

Comment: I edited this post to just ask one question.

Comment: Yes, the distance - measured vertically - between the nodes using your code does appear to be the same.

Comment: I am looking for a simple modification, as I described in my other post. I have not seen these commands and would prefer not to download these extra packages for this one modification.

Comment: If you can define a length between `(label_for_Vertex_b.south)` and `(label_for_Farey_Fraction_at_Vertex_b.north)` and use that distance to position the fraction `(2n+1)/2` on the last graph, and from this node, draw the horizontal line of the last simple graph, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @user74973, I offer you a solution, which have different approach to draw you image. Apparently you not like it, so you need to wait some another answer.

Comment: For a great work is very important gratify it.