# Error in an incredibly short code for TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I be getting an error in this code for a TikZ diagram? All that I am trying to do is call a vertex "$P$"! The error message that I get is "I do not know the key 'tikz/pics/fpic' to which you passed '\coordinate (P) at (0,0)', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,arrows.meta,bending}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}



\begin{document}



\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}

[nodes={inner sep=0, font=\scriptsize,
execute at begin node={\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0.5ex}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0.75ex}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0.5ex}}},
shorten/.style={shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1},
pics/fpic/.style={code={#1}}, x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm]

%A forest with a vertex P is drawn.

\matrix[row sep=4.5em]{\pic{fpic={
\coordinate (P) at (0,0);
}};
};
%
%



\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what the error says, there is no predefined `pic` by the name `fpic` ...

Comment: You presumably copied this from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529715/inserting-a-key-in-a-tikz-diagram you could have said

Comment: @David Carlisle  Wrong.  This diagram only has one vertex, and there is no vertex called "P" in the diagram that you cited.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  How do I get the code to compile?

Comment: @user143462 but that is the first hit searching for `\pic{fpic` and it has the same preamble with the same comments (but it works and defines the needed code) the code posted here looks like parts of that with needed parts removed.

Comment: @David Carlisle  Just added the node command.  Still is not compiling.

Comment: @user143462 Perhaps you should clarify what you're trying to do. Why do you want do use this `fpic` key? Why are you using code from this other question? What kind of diagram are you trying to do?

Comment: @Vincent  This is what I am trying to do. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643051/concise-code-to-get-four-identical-diagrams-equally-spaced-in-four-quadrants

Comment: so I assume that by "wrong" you meant "yes, you were right, I did copy the code from that answer" ? Or where did you get the idea to use an undefined key `fpic` ?

Comment: @David Carlisle  Actually, I got the code for the options for the `tikzpicture` environment from another diagram that I have in my files. (I had also made a post about it on this website.) I didn't want anyone to be distracted by that post.

Comment: @David Carlisle I am glad that you found it, though, so that I could add those options to the `tikzpicture` environment and see what was wrong with the code on my LaTeX editor.  (I had those options for the `tikzpicture` environment on the editor on my computer. Somehow, I didn't copy-and-paste them into the code for my post, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original error is as mentioned in the comments due to the fact that you were using a `pic` that wasn't defined anywhere: `fpic`. As David mentions, one possible definition of `fpic` is found in [Inserting a key in a TikZ diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529715/inserting-a-key-in-a-tikz-diagram), so you could perhaps use that.

In your updated code you've made two mistakes:

- the empty line between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and the next `[`.
- no `\\` at the end of `\matrix`. In a TikZ `\matrix`, every single row has to be ended with `\\`.

Here is a complete example including only the necessary bits.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  % define fpic
  pics/fpic/.style={code={#1}},
]

\matrix[row sep=4.5em]{\pic{fpic={
\coordinate (P) at (0,0);
}}; \\ % <-- all rows in a TikZ \matrix must end with \\
};
%

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I say "necessary", I mean for this example only. I don't know what you're intending to do, but you may or may not need the code from that other question I didn't include here.

Comment: I don't know how I put a blank line between the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and the optional arguments when posting. I was literally choking on something and couldn't see what I was editing. Ugghhh. The mistake in my edited code was not having the "\\" after the only row in the matrix environment. (How do you typeset the code for two backslash characters and highlight it as code?) I had assumed that since there was only one row, I wouldn't need it.

Comment: The reason for this post is that I am trying to do this. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643051/concise-code-to-get-four-identical-diagrams-equally-spaced-in-four-quadrants

Comment: If you want to help me there, I would really appreciate it.